# More about odd numbers in Pascal's triangle

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Do you have any references to this interesting result? I could not find any...

The total number of odd numbers in the first $2^n$ rows of Pascal's triangle is $3^n$, $n>=0$.

It's easy to prove by induction based on the formula for the number of odds in row $n$ ($2^m$, where $m$ is the number of ones in the binary expansion of $n$).

Comment: Just saw it: the answer by @Micah to the "Odds in Pascal's Triangle" post includes a direct proof of this fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences lists as entry [A006046](http://oeis.org/A006046)

> Total number of odd entries in first n rows of Pascal's triangle: a(0) = 0, a(1) = 1, a(2k) = 3*a(k), a(2k+1) = 2*a(k) + a(k+1)

which doesn't give the claim explicitly but makes it very clear implicitly. Further down, in the formula section, you can find it explicitly:

> a(2^n) = 3^n. - Henry Bottomley, Apr 05 2001